# fetch all users of a chat conversation

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a chat system where there will always be 2 people.
A user can have many different conversations

I am designing it with 2 tables: **Conversations** and **Messages**

**Conversations table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('conversations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_me');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_you');

            $table->foreign('id_me')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('id_you')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Messages table**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('conversation_id');
            $table->text('msg');
            $table->boolean('read')->default(false);

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('conversation_id')->references('id')->on('conversations');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Conversation Model**

```
public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }
```

**User Model**

```
public function conversations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Conversation::class, 'id_me')->orWhere('id_you', $this->id);
    }
```

Currently I can fetch the conversations with the relation $user->conversations but I need to fetch the users of each conversation and I don't know how to do it.
I don't know how to approach it, any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this.

**Conversation Model**

```
public function me()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_me');
}


public function you()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_you');
}
```

and then use these **$conversation->me** , **$conversation->you**